# assistance with getting web deploy from visual studio set up

Tags: iis-7.5, visual-studio-2012, publishing, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am working on getting web deploy set up on IIS 7.5. I have followed the steps exactly in this article:

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler

I have tested importing and exporting applications on the server and all work perfectly. Now I would like to set up remote access to ms deploy so I can install web applications by publishing in visual studio 2012 with publish profiles.

Here is where I am confused, what is the url I include in this for the service url (ie. msdeploy.axd)? Where I can find it on the servers iis (server is located on different machine than visual studio)? I have read about access is over port 8172, how can I check that this is open for communication?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, the installation instructions you want are [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy) in the "Install" section of the site. The instructions you linked are from 2008.

Once you've installed MSDeploy v3 as per the newer instructions, the `MSDeployServiceURL` value will be `https://webserver:8172/msdeploy.axd`. You'll also probably need to set `<AllowUntrustedCertificate>true</AllowUntrustedCertificate>` if you don't have a cert on the server.

The user in question will need to be an administrator unless you have setup non-administrator deployments (instructions in the same link).